# Bad operand types for binary operator. First Type: BigInteger Second Type: BigInteger

Tags: java

So I have a method that uses 3 variables (`i`, `factorial`, and `number`) and returns a `BigInteger`. `number` and `i` are `int`s and `factorial` is a `BigInteger`. Within my method, I have a for loop that goes as follows

```
public static BigInteger bigIntegerFactorialMethod(int number){
    int i =  1;
    BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
  
    for(i = 1; i <= number; i++){
        factorial = factorial * BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        i++;
    }
  
    return factorial;
}
```

On the sixth line, I get the title of this question as an error where the factorial is being updated in the for loop.

> Bad operand types for binary operator '*'. First Type: `BigInteger` Second Type: `BigInteger`"

I'm guessing it's because I'm not comparing the right properties of the object and the system doesn't know what to compare?

Comment: infix operators are only defined on primitives, not objects. For multiplication. we should use method `Biginteger::multiply`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to multiply objects using '*' operator.
Also, I see you increment variable 'i' twice (in for and in body of cycle).

It might look like this:

```
public static BigInteger bigIntegerFactorialMethod(int number) {
    BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

    // here we start from 2 because we already have '1'
    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for `BigInteger` you need to use the `multiply` method.

```java
factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

Additionally, as a recommendation, you can reduce your method.
You can use `BigInteger.ONE`, instead of `BigInteger.valueOf(1)`.

```java
public static BigInteger bigIntegerFactorialMethod(int number){
    BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int term = 1; term <= number; term++)
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(term));
    return factorial;
}
```

Here is the result when `number` is 10.

```
2432902008176640000
```